# only home page is showing all other pages is showing error 404 in xampp codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, xampp

I'm using **CODEIGNITER**. I installed a project which is working fine as online but when I copied files in localhost (XAMPP) then only home page is working file, all other page is showing below message:

> **Not Found**
>   The requested URL /maharajaviaggi/team was not found on this server.
>   Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
>   Apache/2.2.9 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8h mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.2.6 Server at localhost Port 80

I am not getting the point Why it is showing this as this is working fine online...?

Comment: Check your base_url() in the config file.

Comment: Check your file and class names have a read of this http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the problem is related with htaccess

if you are using php as a module on apache your .htaccess should be like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

if you are using it as cgi or fpm

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: this is showing below error Server error! The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script. If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster. Error 500 localhost 10/30/16 17:16:14 Apache/2.2.9 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8h mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.2.6

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your **.htaccess** file next to the index.php looks like something like this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Then go to your config, and change these lines to :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/your_project_name/';  
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: this is showing below error



**Server error!**

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 500

localhost
10/30/16 17:16:14
Apache/2.2.9 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8h mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.2.6

Comment: Check if there is multiple .htaccess files and have them all the same, they might be more in your codeigniter application.

Comment: yes
I have one .htaccess in at root level with application folder.
second is inside application folder.

#Deny from all

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

  
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    #This last condition enables access to the images and css folders, and the robots.txt file
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|images|robots\.txt|css|docs|cache)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>

Comment: maybe its an error with your xampp installation, try to check if the mod rewrite module is active and running. if nothing works, uninstall xampp and try on wamp.

Comment: then it is your classes names, make sure the classes are first letter capitalized, and also make sure the files a first letter capitalized as well. It can't be other than this.

Comment: you means files name in view like index.php. it should be Index.php in Codeignitor..Am I right....?

Comment: views can be named anything, but Classes names and Controllers names should be like this :

Comment: --> Controller : Index.php
--> Controller Class name : Class Index extends

Comment: k
thanks
I m new to CI so I didnot know naming rules.
I will implement as you say and revert you.

Comment: problem has solved when I uploaded my project to online server, localhost xampp is not allowing any other page to show.